# WebCrypto decrypt with AES-GCM returns 'DOMException' when data comes from socket.io server

Tags: encryption, socket.io, arraybuffer

I am writing an encrypted chat using socket.io (node.js)

Client1 encryption:

```
let encryptedData = await encrypt(text); 
//encryptedData returns: {message: ArrayBuffer type, iv: Uint8Array type}
socket.emit('message', encryptedData);   //Send to server
```

Server:

```
socket.on('message' (data) => {
  io.to(client2).emit('answer', data); // Sends the received encrypted message to Client2
});
```

Client2 decryption:

```
socket.on('answer', async function(answer){
   //answer returns: {message: ArrayBuffer type, iv: ArrayBuffer type} //Why `iv` is ArrayBuffer instead of Uint8Array?
   let decryptedData = await decrypt(answer.message, answer.iv); //Returns DOMException !
   //I've also tried converting answer.iv to Uint8Array type, but nothing has changed.
});
```

Here is encrypt/decrypt code (client side):

```
async function encrypt(plainText){
   currentIV = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
   let message = new TextEncoder().encode(plainText);
    return {
     message: await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({ 
         name: "AES-GCM",
         iv: currentIV },
         secret,
         message), 
     iv: currentIV 
    }
 }
 async function decrypt(encryptMessage, iv){
      let decryptMessage = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({ 
          name: "AES-GCM",
          iv: iv },
          secret,
          encryptMessage);
      return new TextDecoder().decode(decryptMessage);
 }
```

Two clients share the same secret, one of them encrypts the message before sending, then sends the encrypted `message` to the other client as an ArrayBuffer, and `iv` as a Uint8Array.

On the other side, the user receives this data in a slightly different form, I don't understand why. It receives `message` as an ArrayBuffer, but `iv` instead of type Uint8Array gets ArrayBuffer type.

The encryption/decryption functions work well as the message is successfully decrypted before it is sent:
Client1:

```
   let encryptedData = await encrypt(text);
   let decryptedData = await decrypt(encryptedData.message, encryptedData.iv);
   console.log(decryptedData); // Shows the decrypted message
   socket.emit('message', encryptedData);
```

But if you send them through the socket server, an error will appear.

I will be very happy if someone knows how to help, thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Before sending the `iv`, I converted it to an ArrayBuffer, and then on the client2 after receiving I converted it back to Unit8Array:

Client1:

```
 let encryptedData = await encrypt(text);
 console.log({message: encryptedData.message, iv: encryptedData.iv.buffer});
 socket.emit('message', {message: encryptedData.message, iv: encryptedData.iv.buffer});
```

Client2:

```
socket.on('answer', async function(answer){
       console.log(answer);
       let decryptedData = await decrypt(answer.message, new Uint8Array(answer.iv));
});
```

But this did not help, the same error still appears.
I printed the data to the console before sending and after, to compare, and noticed that the `[[ArrayBufferData]]` property does not match:

Before sending:

```
  > iv:   ArrayBuffer(12)
          byteLength: (...)
          [[Prototype]]: ArrayBuffer
          [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(12)
          [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(12)
          [[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(6)
          [[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(3)
          [[ArrayBufferByteLength]]: 12
          [[ArrayBufferData]]: "0x612a02018000" 
  > message: ArrayBuffer(17)
             byteLength: (...)
             [[Prototype]]: ArrayBuffer
             [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(17)
             [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(17)
             [[ArrayBufferByteLength]]: 17
             [[ArrayBufferData]]: "0x612a0201c000"
             [[Prototype]]: Object
```

After receiving:

```
  > iv:   ArrayBuffer(12)
          byteLength: (...)
          [[Prototype]]: ArrayBuffer
          [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(12)
          [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(12)
          [[Int16Array]]: Int16Array(6)
          [[Int32Array]]: Int32Array(3)
          [[ArrayBufferByteLength]]: 12
          [[ArrayBufferData]]: "0x302c01c1c000" // This property is not the same as before the submission.
  > message: ArrayBuffer(17)
             byteLength: (...)
             [[Prototype]]: ArrayBuffer
             [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array(17)
             [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array(17)
             [[ArrayBufferByteLength]]: 17
             [[ArrayBufferData]]: "0x302c01c18000" // This property is not the same as before the submission
             [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Someone understands why this behavior?

Comment: Maybe typed arrays cannot be processed. Try to send the IV as `ArrayBuffer` (and convert it to `Uint8Array` afterwards if needed). You should also check if the received data matches the sent data.

Comment: @Topaco thanks for your reply. I did as you said, but nothing changed, I also changed the question, I added a comparison of data before sending and after and noticed that one property does not match. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The data you are comparing appear to be addresses. They may be different. You have to compare the _contents_ of the ArrayBuffers.

Comment: @Topaco I compared the contents of the ArrayBuffer before sending and after and they are the same. I tried to send the encrypted data back to myself, not to the client2, and there was no error, I am even more confused. `io.to(socket.id).emit('answer', data)`

Comment: @Topaco I figured out what the problem was, the problem is a shared secret, I forgot to save it in indexeDB and it was returning null. The data is fine, thank you for your help.